# CPU usage in top on a VPS

Tags: vps

When running TOP on our VPS the idle CPU usage number doesn't change. Is this a property of a VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Idle CPU usage doesn't really count. It's resources aren't being spent, it's just as it says, idle. :-) I'm talking out from a linux perspective. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the case with my virtual machines in OpenVZ.  Do you know if this is OpenVZ, XEN, or something else?

Comment: Not sure - where can I look to find this out?